# How to register for push notifications AFTER login/register?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I need to register the user into the installation class in Parse after they login/register, but it does not register. There is no error printed, and when I breakpoint in the appdeleagate nothing happens.

viewDidLoad of viewcontroller after login/register

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            print("saved installation")
        }else{
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Move the settings register to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score -1):

To register to receive push notifications via Apple Push Service you have to call a `registerForRemoteNotifications()` method of `UIApplication`.

If registration succeeds, the app calls your app delegate object’s `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method and passes it a device token.

You should pass this token along to the server you use to generate push notifications for the device. If registration fails, the app calls its app delegate’s `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` method instead.

you can refer this [Appcoda's beginner guide for push notifiction](http://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/)

Update :

```
#pragma mark - push notificaiton
-(void)registerToReceivePushNotification {
// Register for push notifications
UIApplication* application =[UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

nd the two application delegate callbacks are in app delegate

```
// handle user accepted push notification, update parse
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
 // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];

// enable future push to deviceId
NSUUID *identifierForVendor = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSString* deviceId = [identifierForVendor UUIDString];
[currentInstallation setObject:deviceId forKey:@"deviceId"];

[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}


// handle push notification arrives when app is open
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

You can do the registration call at any time - and it is a good idea to only do so when you know in the app you would like the user to receive push notifications.

The two application delegate callbacks have to be in your app delegate though, as you register for notification types on the application delegate and you only have one. I would suggest making an application delegate method to call that then does the registration, you could call it from your view controller through [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] (cast the result of that call to your application delegate class).

code is in `objective-c` convert it in swift.

hope this will help :)

Comment: I understand this part, but what if there is a login/register, and I want the pop up to accept the notification after the login is successful?

Comment: check my updated answer. It have objective c code, convert it in swift and i don't think that this hard to do. :)